# How to prevent the class to compile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, compilation

I have a large library. And there are various customers who need only a portion of the library. I want to be able to compile for a specific customer only the necessary classes.

example:

```
[Compile("Sanderson","Denis")
class CreateUser
{
}
```

and this class compile if I set in webconfig name Sanderson or Denis.

Comment: totally messy: create build targets with specific compilation symbols, which then can be used with `#if foo`... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can only do conditional compilation with the [`#if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) directive. Create one or more [project configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) and in each of them add the necessary options to [define some constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (most conveniently through the project designer's [Build page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) that you will be testing for with `#if`.

Assuming e.g. you are using the parameter `/define:DENIS` you could then do:

```
#if DENIS
class DenisClass {}
#endif
```

Comment: Jon, maybe an example would be useful.

Comment: @linkerro: Added one and also some more links.

Comment: @Jon, I do not fit, I do not want to duplicate code. if I have 10 clients, I need 10 times to duplicate the body of the class, it is not correct.

Comment: Duplicate 10 times why? It sounds like you are simply trying to do something which you should not be doing.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achievable with compiler directives.

```
#define LIBCLASS_A

 #if (LIBCLASS_A)
 {
  // Your class
 }
```

Comment: you can also use build targets, and inject such variables (tab "build" in project-properties, textbox "conditional compilation symbols")